# When trying to install Python3 on an Intel Chromebook - getting error "Sudo: user does not exist in passwd database"

Tags: linux, sudo, chromebook, python3

I'm trying to run Python 3 on Linux. My Device is Chromebook with Intel processor. I've tried downloading python by 2 different methods. I'm new to coding and trying to learn. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean? the title is not reflected in your question description!

Comment: It's best that you are specific about which two methods you used to install Python and what command returned that output.  However Python3 is probably installed already - just run `python3` at the command line.  You can also enter  `python` then press Tab to see all installed programs starting with the word python.